# How to go about deployment of ASP.Net 4.5 / MVC 4 /SQL Express 2008 R2 to a Windows Azure Free Website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, hosting, azure-sql-database, publishing

*I am very new to Windows Azure - have been into asp.net for about 10 years now and have been deploying applications via Database backup and restore on production and copy of final code bits from source control to the root folder on production database.*

I am doing my initial reading and finding it a bit difficult to absorb the overall process of deploying an ASP.Net MVC web Application to Azure.

I have managed to have the database and the website code on Azure and it is up and running, but I can't get to terms on the following points and want to understand them better to have a regular deployment on place as versions of my app keep going up.

1. Database doesn't work like backup a local database and then upload .bak file and restore to the production server.
2. Nor can I see my website files.

---

Update: 04-Aug-2013
Azure Websites have an FTP option. You can see your FTP host name in respective website Dashboard. The username and password for FTP are located in the publish settings file (note: you got to pick up the FTP username and password, NOT the publish username/password. They both are different.

---

When I am getting ready for version 2.0 of my product, how do I get the database from the Azure SQL, upgrade it to 2.0 and put it back?

I assume the publishing wizard from Visual Studio should be able to take care of code upgrade, but how do I edit my production web.config file on the fly?

How do I take my website offline and show users my custom "offline" page when I am in the middle of the upgrade? (Stopping the website shows up the Windows Azure site not available page).

Comment: I never use Azure, but maybe their tutorial can help you, http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/get-started/. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For your database backup / upgrade questions

For migration of databases to SQL Azure (or pulling them down) the SQL Database Migration Wizard has proven to be a lifesaver for me, get it here:

http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

This will pull and push both data and schema for your database.

### For seeing your website files

You won't be able to if you are using Windows Azure Websites.

### For editing web.config on fly

You can't. BUT -- you can edit connection strings and appsettings through the **'configure'** tab of your website like so:
[image: app settings & conn strings]

### Turning your website offline during upgrade

While you cannot specifically use the app_offline route without another deployment. One thing you could do is change your default document. This is easily done right in the same **'configure'** tab for the website in the portal as I mentioned above, see here:
[image: default document]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering to my most pressing points. The offline app was the most important one. Thanks.

Comment: Since the web.config cannot be edited on the fly, does this mean that I have always got to modify the local web.config and use the publish wizard to publish it?

Comment: To modify the web.config, yes - you'd have to publish it in some way. I'd recommend creating an account on visualstudio.com (it is FREE) and using either TFS or git, then create some builds there that suit your needs.

Comment: My Source Control is Plastic SCM. I don't think Plastic SCM is supported by Azure as a Source Control nor has Plastic SCM announced any Azure integration. Will have to just wait till they start integrating. Thanks for the pointer though.